# Opencart change languge with currency change options

Tags: php, opencart, multilingual

I am just a newbie to [opencart](http://www.opencart.com/) . I have made an ecommerce wesite with it. In that website there is the feature for multilingual with multi currency converter option. Now I want that when a user clicks on his language it should also convert the currency to his language as well. So is it possible to do this with [Opencart](http://www.opencart.com/). Can someone share any codes or any reference link so that I can do that. Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a currency option in the opencart admin panel  , the path is something like this :

system > localisation > currencies

there you can change and add currency options related to a particular language.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I want to convert both language and currency as well. That will only change the language.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($currency && $this->has($currency)) {
            $symbol_left   = $this->currencies[$currency]['symbol_left'];
            $symbol_right  = $this->currencies[$currency]['symbol_right'];
            $decimal_place = $this->currencies[$currency]['decimal_place'];
        } else {
            if($_SESSION['language']=="es"):

                $symbol_right  = $this->currencies[$this->code]['symbol_right'];
                else:
    $from="USD";
    $to="MXN";
    $path = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1".$from."=?".$to;
    $rawdata = file_get_contents($path);
    $data = explode('"', $rawdata);
    $data = explode(' ', $data['3']);
    $var = $data['0'];
    $e=round($var,3);
    if ($e):
        $number=$number / $e;
    else:
        $default_dollar=12.863;
        $number=$number / $default_dollar;                    
    endif;    
        $symbol_right=" USD";
    endif;
            $symbol_left   = $this->currencies[$this->code]['symbol_left'];

            $decimal_place = $this->currencies[$this->code]['decimal_place'];

            $currency = $this->code;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function at :\system\library\currency.php

```
    public function format($number, $currency = '', $value = '', $format = true) {
    if ($currency && $this->has($currency)) {
        $symbol_left   = $this->currencies[$currency]['symbol_left'];

        $symbol_right  = $this->currencies[$currency]['symbol_right'];
        $decimal_place = $this->currencies[$currency]['decimal_place'];
    } else {            
        $symbol_left   = $this->currencies[$this->code]['symbol_left'];
        $symbol_right  = $this->currencies[$this->code]['symbol_right'];
        $decimal_place = $this->currencies[$this->code]['decimal_place'];           
        $currency = $this->code;
    }
```

if you look carefully you can change the currency here as per the language or you can use jquery to send an ajax request for the currency change.